# Node Js how to fetch data from database in an hierarchical way

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, mongoose

I'm writing a back code using NodeJs to fetch some data from backend,  I want dataBase data  to be  like this
like this:

```js
data = [{
  name: "Admin",
  id: '1',
  children: [
    { name: "Admin", id: "1" },
    { name: "groupe1", id: "2" },
    {
      name: "groupe2", id: "1455", children: [
        { name: "groupe2", id: "1455" },
        { name: "gro", id: "5444" },
        { name: "hhrr", id: "45" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

the idea is simple we have a list of group each group has a parent I want to display all the groups list in an hierarchical way the top one of the tree is done
Some groups are parents and groups in the same time and some others are only groups if the group is not parent we add an object with its name and ID in the array of children of his parent
if this groups is a parent that's mean it has children we add an object with its ID and name in the array of children of his parents, and we add property children for the object which is array named children with for the first time an object with the name and the id of the group etc...

i tryed to do this but it did not work

```
const getParentsByType = async ({ name, _id }) => {

      let parentResult = [
        {
          id: _id,
          name: name,
          children: [
            {
              id: _id,
              name: name,
            },
          ],
        },
      ];
     parentResult= await findParent(_id, parentResult[0].children, 0);
     return parentResult;
    };

    const findParent = async (parentId, parentResult, itemPos) => {
      let children = await Models.GroupModel.find({ parent: parentId, status: true }).select('name  _id');
      for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        let childrenList = await Models.GroupModel.find({ parent: children[i]._id, status: true }).select('name  _id');
    
        if (childrenList.length != 0) {
          parentResult.push(buildParentWithChild(children[i]._id, children[i].name));
          findParent(children[i]._id,parentResult.children[i],itemPos++)
        } else {
          parentResult.push(buildParent(children[i]._id, children[i].name));
        }
      }
      return parentResult
    };
```

and this the model of the data base

```
const Group = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  status: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
  },
 
  
  parent: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Group',
  },
 
 

});
```

i had two days trying to resolve tis but with no result
i need some helps and Thank you

Comment: where are these functions/methods  `buildParentWithChild` and `buildParent`.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing your returned data. It validates your data as objects i dont see any problem with your function regardless i still have no idea what format your a trying to build.

```
let children = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await Models.GroupModel.find({ parent: parentId, status: true }).select('name  _id')));
let childrenList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await Models.GroupModel.find({ parent: children[i]._id, status: true }).select('name  _id')));
```

Comment: no i want to display tha data in a specific way

Comment: Yes but use this to wrap all your await Models.GroupModel....

Comment: the problem is not with the querry but the problem is with the logic of the function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to convert the array returned by `Models.GroupModel.find`, and which looks like

```js
var dbresult = [
  {_id: "1", parent: null, name: "one"},
  {_id: "2", parent: "1", name: "two"}
];
```

into a hierarchical structure. This can be done with a function that adds all children of a given parent `p`, including, recursively, their children. Like the following:

```js
function children(p) {
  var result = [];
  for (r of dbresult) if (r.parent === p) {
    var row = {_id: r._id, name: r.name};
    var chld = children(r._id);
    if (chld.length > 0) row.children = chld;
    result.push(row);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(children(null)));
```

Note that this approach requires only *one* database access (to fill the `dbresult`) and is therefore probably faster than your `findParent` function.

Comment: always there is a parent it can not be null

Comment: In you example, Admin 1 seems to be its own parent. But then it must also occur as its own child: `{name:"Admin",id:"1",children:[{name:"Admin",id:"1",...}]}`, which leads to infinite recursion. Why didn't you set Admin 1's parent to `null`?

Comment: that's an exemple of the output wich i want to reach

Comment: If Admin 1 is a child of itself, then the entry `{name:"Admin",id:"1"}` in your desired output must have a `children` member, but it does not. And it cannot have one, because that would mean infinite recursion. That's why no entry should be its own parent.

Comment: no ! if a group is a group and parent in the same time it means the value of dbResult.parent  is the this group it wil be add to the children of his parents like this {name:"Admin",id:"1",children:[{name:"Admin",id:"1"}]}

Comment: Please include in your question how your data looks when it comes from the database (the `dbresult`).

Comment: i add the model of the db result

Comment: Please also show the _data_. Which entries are their own parent? In particular, what's the parent of `groupe2`?

Comment: this is an exemple of the data {
_id :637b84bd470a647cb16fb41d
name:"test15"
status:true
type :6372573b484e3808fff82cce
parent:6372573b484e3808fff82cce
}  and the parent is the id of the group parent